# What would it take to build an eddystone/physical web beacon management cloud platform

Tags: cloud, eddystone

I would like to know what it would take to build, an eddystone or physical web beacon management and content creation platform? can it be done by one person what tools would you require?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few layers to your question. People that have approached building a content platform for the Physical Web often tackle two separate pieces.

The first is likely a URL manager (but this isn't required). As the Eddystone beacon can't hold a large URL, many people need to user a URL shortener. This are very easy to build but by making your own, you can add extra features, like group beacon management so it is easier to organize and track your beacon usage.

The second is your CMS. But this is a very broad issue and there are many CMSes out there already. If you're going to build one, you'll likely need to find your specific focus/industry that you'd like to cater to. As the Physical Web becomes more widely used, people are going to want to 'put up a beacon in their store' quickly and a product that lets them do this quickly and easily will be very valuable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have more clarity on what you wish to build.
Once, you know what you want to build and the purpose of it, then you would automatically know the technology to build it.

Physical web platforms are nothing but web applications(look for progressive web apps). Physical web is just a way of engaging with your web application in physical world.